# How to dynamically create mixed HTML content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Considering I want to create this HTML dynamically:

```
<li><img src="a"/>some text</li>
```

Some text is a text string that is potentially unsafe, let's say is stored in variable 'some_text'.

The idea is to call `$('<li>').append($('<img>').attr({src:"a"}), ... );`

Using `$(some_text)` is bad idea because it's unsafe.

Using `text(some_text)` doesn't work because the text is not an only child of an element.

I do not want to wrap the text into a `<span>`

I do not want to invent/use a function that sanitizes or escapes the string

Comment: Why don't you want to sanitize the text --- I can't imagine that there is any other way to keep from having security issues -- that's why php, angular, and every thing else does sanitize.  So? what is your goal and why is a function now a good solution?

Comment: Because jQuery has functions that deal with arbitrary text safely (i.e. `text()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, but possibly the simplest is to first add the text content to the li element and then prepend the image to get the correct order.

```
$('<li>').text(some_text).prepend($('<img>').attr({src:"a"}), ... );
```